# App Invite configuration failed Firebase iOS cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-invites

I got a build error with this in it while trying out the new version of firebase

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.appinvite', reason: 'App Invite configuration failed.'
```

Answer (score 37):

1. Click on your project
2. Navigate to Info tab
3. Scroll down you will see the **URL Types**
4. Click the + button and add your **bundleID** to **URL Schemes**
5. Click the + button again and add your **REVERSED_CLIENT_ID** to **URL Schemes**. This can be found in your GoogleService-Info.plist

Finally your URL types should look something like this
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The Invites pod does require setting up a couple of custom URL schemes, which is easy to skip over. You can do this in you Info.plist, or in the General tab of the target in Xcode. The two custom URL schemes are:

1. Your bundle ID. e.g. "com.foo.bar"
2. Your Google Sign In client ID with the components reversed. e.g. "com.googleusercontent.apps.12345678-xxxxxxxxx".

The second one is trickier! In the `GoogleService-Info.plist` you downloaded there should be a key *REVERSED_CLIENT_ID* you can copy the value of. For what its worth, I find that the first build after I edit the custom URL types doesn't seem to register it properly, so if it doesn't work right away, just try again.

Answer (score 4):

My podfile had the following. I just had to uncomment the Firebase/Invites pod. There seems to be a problem with it for now.

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/AppIndexing'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
#pod 'Firebase/Invites' this caused an exception!!
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Invites works over `Firebase Dynamic Links` so, by following the [Dynamic Links guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios#create-a-dynamic-link-programmatically), you need to setup 2 things in your project:

1. Add Url type
   [image]

At Target settings, info tab, add the new url. Set the schema your bundle ID. If you use other schema you have to set it on Dynamic Links page at Firebase console.

2. Associate the Firebase Dynamic link domain in your app.
   [image]
   Go to Firebase console and copy from Dynamic links section the
   `Firebase-generated Dynamic Link Domain` of your app.
   Go to target settings, capability tab, and enable Associated Domains.
   Add the `Firebase-generated Dynamic Link Domain` you just copied.

This should fix the configuration error as it did in my case. Anyway i advise to read the full guide.